# How to allow a user to input a number to get back a value in a sorted list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list statePop2015=[State, population], which goes on for all 50 states. My assignment is to add a function that allows the user to get the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc most populous state. The function is called rank. This function takes a number and returns the state and its population. For example:

```
print(rank(1, statePop2015))
>>>("California", 39144818)
```

So far I have attempted to ask the user for their input for the rank number, sort the list in descending order, and then try to return the list by the rank number.

```
num = int(input("Enter the number of the state that you want."))

def rank(num):
    sorted(statePop2015, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=true)
    return(statePop2015(num))
```

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: What does your `rank()` method return?  Do you see any errors?  What *exactly* are you asking?

Comment: Hints: 1) `sorted` returns a *new* list and 2) you use `[]` to get elements from a list.

Comment: Your function has two lines and at least three mistakes, one of which will produce an error (and when you fix it you'll get another error). I'd say it's back to the drawing board.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the following function :

```
def rank(n): 
    x=[i[::-1] for i in l] # l is statePop2015
    x.sort()
    x=x[::-1]
    return x[n-1][1],x[n-1][0]
```

Answer (score -1):

`sorted` does not alter the iterable it is applied to, you have to reassign the result (or return from there). Also, you access indexed list elements via `[]`, not `()`:

```
def rank(num):
    return sorted(statePop2015, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[num]
```

Comment: `sorted` returns a list in Python 3 as well.

Comment: Also, you've still got a `NameError`.